# Setting PyDev "Search" to case insensitive by default

Tags: pydev

I know this sounds like a newbie question, but I've been using PyDev for years and never run into this till now. I've searched Google for hours to no available. I feel like I'm overlooking something really simple, but...

In PyDev, when I search (ctrl-H), the dialog box *always* has "Case Sensitive" checked when it first comes up. I'm 99.5% sure this didn't use to be the case for me. However, I cannot seem to locate the setting that turns off Case Sensitive by default.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesn't seem to happen to me... when I do Ctrl+H the case-sensitive is unchecked. Which PyDev/Eclipse versions are you using? Which OS? Do you have some error in your error log? (see http://pydev.org/faq.html for how to get it)

p.s.: Note that in an existing search it'll reload the configuration you used last for it.